# Dúvida em consulta SQL oracle - coautor

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, oracle

Olá, tenho a seguinte consulta para executar no Oracle SQL Developer:

"Liste o par de autores com potencial colaboração, baseando-se que eles nunca publicaram juntos, porém tem
um dos seus co-autores em comum."

Consegui desenvolver o script abaixo e travei, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
select c.authorname, a.idauth, count(distinct b.idauth) - 1 as coautor
from publish a inner join publish b
on a.idpub = b.idpub
inner join authors c
on c.idauthors = a.idauth
group by a.idauth, c.authorname
order by a.idauth;
```

As minhas tabelas são:

> ```
> AUTHORS: idauthors, authorname     
> PUBLICATIONS: idpublication, codepublication, booktitle, journalname, numberpub, publisher ,title, volumepub, year, schoolname, pages, chapter, typepub     
> PUBLISH: idpub, idauth
> ```

Comment: Isto é exercicio ou problema real ? Acho interessante pois pode ser aplicar a outros casos , conseguiu evoluir ? Pensei aqui e não vi caminho , acho que a solução passaria por uma tabela auxiliar , tipo cursor etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não tenho as tabelas para testar então não testei o código.

Eu começaria por aqui:

```sql
WITH coauthors AS (
    -- O DISTINCT remove multiplas coautorias
    SELECT DISTINCT a.idauth AS author,
           b.idauth AS coauthor 
    FROM   publish a 
    JOIN   publish b
    -- Autores que publicaram juntos
    ON     a.idpub = b.idpub
    -- E que não são a mesma pessoa
    AND    a.idauth <> b.idauth 
) SELECT DISTINCT a.author AS author_a,
         b.author AS author_b
FROM coauthors a
JOIN coauthors b 
-- autores com os mesmos coautores
ON   a.coauthor = b.coauthor
-- que nao sao a mesma pessoa
AND  a.author <> b.author
-- e que nunca publicaram juntas
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM coauthors c 
    WHERE c.author = a.author 
    AND   c.coauthor = b.author
)
```